# CSS selector error - Submenu not showing on Hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors, hover, css-transitions

Been battling with getting my Submenu to show on hover, it works but as soon as I slide off the parent element '.dropdown-toggle', the Submenu disappears.

Been trying for hours to fix this, look at the code below and see if you can solve the issue please.

Much appreciated

```
  .dropdown-menu {
     position: absolute;
     top: 40px;
     border: none;
     padding: 0;
     border-radius: 0;
     width: 200px;
     background: #e8e8e8;
     visibility:hidden;
     opacity:0;
     filter:alpha(opacity=0);
     -webkit-transition:700ms ease;
     -moz-transition:700ms ease;
     -o-transition:700ms ease;
     transition:700ms ease;
     }

   .dropdown-toggle:hover + .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-menu { 
     display: block; 
     visibility:visible; 
     opacity:1; 
     filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
     }
```

Comment: Your .dropdown-menu needs to be a child element of .dropdown-toggle for :hover to work even when you move out of .dropdown-toggle itself to .dropdown-menu. In your case judging from your css those 2 are siblings, which won't work.

Comment: One workaround would be to add `, .dropdown-menu:hover` to the second selector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this did not work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your all your answers. This was the working solution below.

```
  .dropdown-menu {
   position: absolute;
   top: 40px;
   border: none;
   padding: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   width: 200px;
   background: #e8e8e8;
   visibility:hidden;
   opacity:0;
   filter:alpha(opacity=0);
   -webkit-transition:700ms ease;
   -moz-transition:700ms ease;
   -o-transition:700ms ease;
   transition:700ms ease;
   }


   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-menu { 
    display: block; 
    visibility:visible; 
    opacity:1; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few changes can solve this:
dropdown-toggle changed to dropdown-menu.(Parent changed)

```
.dropdown-menu {
     position: absolute;
     top: 33px; /* reduced the gap so that it wont dissapear while hovering on submenu*/
     border: none;
     padding: 0;
     border-radius: 0;
     width: 200px;
     background: #e8e8e8;
     visibility:hidden;
     opacity:0;
     filter:alpha(opacity=0);
     -webkit-transition:700ms ease;
     -moz-transition:700ms ease;
     -o-transition:700ms ease;
     transition:700ms ease;
     }

   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu { 
     display: block; 
     visibility:visible; 
     opacity:1; 
     filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This almost worked, but it steered me in the correct direction, in the end the solution was.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: 700ms ease;
  -moz-transition: 700ms ease;
  -o-transition: 700ms ease;
  transition: 700ms ease;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-toggle:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown-toggle">
  <a>Hover me</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2204/